# js- onclick trigged by a div id defined with a php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables, var

I have js onclick like this

```
$(document).on("click", "#a-div-id", function(e) {...});
```

In my script, my trigger div is not #a-div-id but #the-name-of-the-page defined by a php variable ($pagename)

Is it possible for my js to call that div ? making a var seems not beeing enough.

Comment: yes you can echo your PHP variable and use it as the ID in your jQuery file.

Comment: Is that code in a .js file or in a .php file?

Comment: i tried... without success...

Comment: @apokryfos the file is .php and the code is between <script>

Comment: use <?= $myDiv ?>

Comment: @Odjone what happened when you echoed the ID dynamically?

Comment: `$(document).on("click", <?= $pagename ?>, function(e) {...});`  should work, if it doesn't then let us know what the observed problems are (nothing happens, JS error, PHP error?)

Comment: hello @apokryfos. if I do this, it seems to work well $(document).on("click", "#<?= $pagename ?>" .......});     put your answer in "answer" so I can validate it =) Thanks a lot mate, I really really was in a dead end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can echo the variable name inside your markup file:

```
$(document).on("click", <?= $pagename ?>, function(e) {...});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your outputting the code you posted via PHP already then just do it like this:

```
printf( "$( '#%s' ).click( function(e){ … } );", $pagename );
```

otherwise you could also just output an extra script block with the resulting output being:

```
var pageName = "whatever-this-page-is-called";
```

and then

```
$('#'+pageName).click( … );
```

But the easiest way I can think of is to ensure the variable-ID-DIV has a certain className, that you simply don't use for anything else:

```
<div id="unguessable" class="lookHereMate thisIsMe weThreeAreOne"></div>
```

then all you need to do is:

```
var handleMe = $( ".lookHereMate:first" );
```